# What does the code comment 'HD, Figure' mean in Java java.lang.Integer class?

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

for example, the JDK method java.lang.Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int):

```
public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-6
    if (i == 0)
        return 32;
    int n = 1;
    if (i >>> 16 == 0) { n += 16; i <<= 16; }
    if (i >>> 24 == 0) { n +=  8; i <<=  8; }
    if (i >>> 28 == 0) { n +=  4; i <<=  4; }
    if (i >>> 30 == 0) { n +=  2; i <<=  2; }
    n -= i >>> 31;
    return n;
}
```

what does the code comment '**HD, Figure 5-6**' mean?

Comment: It looks like a reference to literature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HD = Hacker's Delight. See the [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

> Implementation note: The implementations of the "bit twiddling" methods (such as `highestOneBit` and `numberOfTrailingZeros`) are based on material from Henry S. Warren, Jr.'s Hacker's Delight, (Addison Wesley, 2002).

Comment: Cool man, I think I found the reason that why numberOfLeadingZeros() method does not have negative condition logic: `if(i <0) return 0;` I just download a pdf copy of the HD book, the code example in HD for  numberOfLeadingZeros is:`int ntz(unsigned x) {
...}`, see? the param in HD book is unsigned, but in Java, it is int.I think the programmer who write the java code just copy the code from HD and forgot to optimized the negative condition of signed int param.

Comment: @Jason: I’m very sure that `ntz` means “number of ***t***railing zeros” rather than “number of leading zeros”.

Comment: @Holger I miss spell it, the function name should be nlz(), here is the full copy from HD book: `int nlz(unsigned x) {
int n;
if (x == 0) return(32);
n = 1;
if ((x >> 16) == 0) {n = n +16; x = x <<16;}
if ((x >> 24) == 0) {n = n + 8; x = x << 8;}
if ((x >> 28) == 0) {n = n + 4; x = x << 4;}
if ((x >> 30) == 0) {n = n + 2; x = x << 2;}
n = n - (x >> 31);
return n;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There are also such comments in `java.lang.Long` and `java.lang.Math`.

For example, the `addExact`method in `java.lang.Math`:

```
public static int addExact(int x, int y) {
    int r = x + y;
    // HD 2-12 Overflow iff both arguments have the opposite sign of the result
    if (((x ^ r) & (y ^ r)) < 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    }
    return r;
}
```

For information of Hacker's Delight we can also refer to: http://hackersdelight.org/